# SiteBreadCrumbs- How to avoid Site Pages

Tags: spfx, pnp, sitepages, reactjs

I'm making use of the [github code](https://github.com/RaspeR87/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/spfx-react-controls/Breadcrumb) to display breadcrumbs in my site. The code uses [pnp control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/SiteBreadcrumb/) to render the content. Is there a way we can modify this to avoid Site Pages appearing in the breadcrumb.
When i browse to my home page, the breadcrumb appears as (Site Name)>(Site Pages). I want to remove the 'Site Page' from the crumbs. I don't want the logged in user to browse to the Site Pages library from the link.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.